# How to add flags to RC.EXE through QMake .pro makefiles

Tags: flags, qmake, include-path, rc

I've the following definition in my .pro file:

```
RC_FILE = app.rc
```

This RC file contains a global include at the top:

```
#include "version_info.h"
```

The version_info.h header is on a common header files directory.

Since RC.EXE takes INCLUDE environment variable in consideration, according to MS documentation, my build process batch sets up that accordingly:

```
SET INCLUDE=%PROJECTDIR%\version;%INCLUDE%
...
QMAKE project.pro -spec win32-msvc2008 -r CONFIG += release
```

This works perfect as RC seems to read that INCLUDE var so the "version_info.h" file is including on every RC file properly.

The problem is when I generate a VS solution (or Import it through the VS Addin). The RC invocation does not contain any /I flag (as I expect) but does not read any INCLUDE variable, even when I've setup through system 'environment variables' dialog in XP.

So I'm stuck with this problem, with two alternatives I could not get to work:

- Make VS RC.exe invocation honour the INCLUDE variable (didn't work either as user or system variable).
- Force QMAKE to pass /I flag to RC invocation, and get that /I flag imported into the project settings (Resource Compiler properties).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug is opened in [Qt bugtracker](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-13776)

Until it solves, you have the following solutions:
- hack the generated solution file (see the bug report for details)
- explictely include the header file with path, without relying on INCLUDEPATH (e.g. #include "../../version.h")

Comment: Thank you very much -- I didnt know it was in Bugtracking.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hacky but works fine: use the QMAKE_RC qmake variable in your .pro file (or via arguments for qmake). By default it is defined as `rc` but you can set it as `rc /i<directory> <any-other-rc-flags>`". It would be better if QMAKE supports something like QMAKE_RC_FLAGS but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you noticed, but the bugtracker bug @Bruce mentioned has been closed as of 5.0.0 RC2: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,41984

The variable you need to use is `RC_INCLUDEPATH`.

Comment: RC_INCLUDEPATH indeed exists and [documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#rc-includepath) but it produces space beetween `/i` and `c:\source\stuff` and results in `RC2135: file not found:  my_icon.ico` error. Do you know if this bug is reported somewhere? The `QMAKE_RC` hack works

Comment: @mvidelgauz Sorry, all my knowledge about QMake files comes from a project several years ago to auto-generate them that was abandoned pretty quickly. I do not know if that bug is reported.